# Set conditional breakpoint in lldb

Tags: conditional-statements, breakpoints, lldb

ALL,

I need to set a breakpoint in lldb on OSX so that the program will be stopped the second time it hits.

So what should I add to the following:

```
break set -f myfile.mm -l 100
```

Trying to debug keyboard issue.

TIA!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I setup an LLDB breakpoint firing every 10th time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40615222/how-can-i-setup-an-lldb-breakpoint-firing-every-10th-time)

Comment: @Willeke, nope. Different condition.

Comment: Do you mean 10th time instead of second time? Did you try `help breakpoint set`? Tip: it's easier to use Xcode to debug and set breakpoints.

Comment: @Willeke, not 10th time only second. And yes I looked at the help. Didn;t find anything there. Will try again. About Xcode - I know its simpler and easier, but there is no Xcode project, this is simple "proof of concept" app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `-i` / `--ignore-count` flag. In your example, your command would be:

```
break set -f myfile.mm -l 100 -i 1
```

This would skip the breakpoint `1` time, and stop the second time (and every time after).

For what it's worth, the docs (from `help breakpoint set`) say:

```
-i <count> ( --ignore-count <count> )
    Set the number of times this breakpoint is skipped before stopping.
```

Comment: "the second time, and every other time." might not be right.  ignore counts don't reset themselves.  They count down to 0 and then stay 0.  It would also be quite reasonable for them to reset themselves (feel free to file an ER with http://bugs.llvm.org).  But that's not how they work today.  So "every other time" is only right if you meant EVERY other time the breakpoint is hit, not every OTHER time the breakpoint is hit.  Or something...

Comment: Thanks for catching the ambiguous grammar. I meant EVERY other. I'll reword it.